# How to set SafeAreaView on Menu Drawer from React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement `SafeAreaProvider` and `SafeAreaView` by the `react-native-safe-area-context` lib in my react-native application. My version of react-navigation is 5.

I followed the documentation provided in react-navigation, I wrapped my `NavigationContainer` within `SafeAreaProvider`. And inside my views I inserted the `SafeAreaView`. But my drawer still fills the space on my entire screen.

[image]
[image]

How I need my drawer keep:
[image]

Can you tell me how I can make `SafeAreaView` work in my Menu Drawer?

I put my project in the [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/OOs0xfb1k) so that they can see the whole project.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: SafeAreaView leaves some sort of padding on top (for the status-bar) and bottom (in case of iPhoneX-notch) ... which is exactly what you're currently have

Comment: design your `View` like that and add `borderRadius` so it will look same

Answer (score 0):

Style the content of your drawer in a nested `View` component ... not in the `SafeAreaView`

```
  <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1 }}>
    {/* Here's your container */}
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#3b8324', borderTopLeftRadius: 25, }}>
      <Text>Start</Text>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

To change the width of your drawer, set `drawerWidth` of your `DrawerNavigatorConfig`

```
const DrawerNavigatorConfig = {
  /** ...configs */
  drawerWidth: 200,
};
```

**React Nav 5**

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerStyle={{ width: YOUR_DRAWER_WIDTH }}
  /**...*/
>
```

Comment: Hey Hend, thank you, it worked in parts, my screen is now running `SafeAreaView`, but my Menu Drawer, still filling the entire screen, I insert a new image that shows how I need it to be

Comment: Hey @Hend, thank you very much for your help and I apologize if I got it wrong. I put a `.gif` now showing exactly what I need to do, thank very much again